# How to capture an array-formatted substring from a string

Tags: php, regex, substring, preg-match, square-bracket

I want to get an array-formatted substring which is inside of the `input()`. I used `preg_match` but can't get the entire expression.  It is stopping at the first `)`. How can I match the entire substring?  Thank You.

```
$input="input([[1,2,nc(2)],[1,2,nc(1)]])";
preg_match('@^([^[]+)?([^)]+)@i',$input, $output);
```

Expectation is:

```
'[[1,2,nc(2)],[1,2,nc(1)]]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern match your desired string (also with starting word ≠ ‘input’:

```
@^(.+?)\((.+?)\)$@i
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/aMN9H)**</kbd>

```
^(.+?)   => find any char at start (ungreedy option)
\)       => find one parenthesis 
(.+?)    => find any char (ungreedy option) => your desired match
\)       => find last parenthesis
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
    $input="input([[1,2,nc(2)],[1,2,nc(1)]])";
    preg_match('/input\((.*?\]\])\)/',$input,$matches);
    print_r($matches);
```

**$matches[1]** will contain whole result you need. Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

You want it purely as a string? Use this simple regex:

```
preg_match('/\((.*)\)$/',$input,$matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers have efficiently/accurately answered your question:

For the fastest accurate pattern, use:

```
$input="input([[1,2,nc(2)],[1,2,nc(1)]])";
echo preg_match('/input\((.*)\)/i',$input,$output)?$output[1]:'';
//                                            notice index ^
```

Or a slightly slower pattern that uses 50% less memory by avoiding the capture group, use:

```
$input="input([[1,2,nc(2)],[1,2,nc(1)]])";
echo preg_match('/input\(\K(.*)(?=\))/i',$input,$output)?$output[0]:'';
//                                                  notice index ^
```

Both methods will provide the same output:  `[[1,2,nc(2)],[1,2,nc(1)]]`

Using a greedy `*` quantifier allows the pattern to move passed the nested parentheses and match the entire intended substring.

In the second pattern, `\K` resets the match's starting point and `(?=\))` is a positive lookahead that ensures the entire substring is matched without including the trailing closing parenthesis.

---

EDIT: All that regex convolution aside, because you know your desired substring is wrapped in `input(` and `)`, the best, simplest approach is a non-regex one...

```
$input="input([[1,2,nc(2)],[1,2,nc(1)]])";
echo substr($input,6,-1);
// output: [[1,2,nc(2)],[1,2,nc(1)]]
```

Done.

Comment: @Gamsh I added an even simpler method.  See my edit.